# Extracting part of the input from Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to write a pig script to essentially do the following.

1. Load input from a list of sources. I understand the way to give the list is “s3://prod/propensity/probablitity/#{runDate}/#{partition}/part*”
   So for example if the runDate is 20131020 and partition is 1,3.
   The pig load will load from s3:\ tap-prod/propensity/probablitity/20131020/1/part* and s3:\ tap-prod/propensity/probablitity/20131020/3/part*
2. What I want in the output is to have the current partition as a column as well. So rows read from partition 1 should have a column with value 1 and rows read from partition 3 should have that column value as 3.
3. Currently I pass “s3://tap-prod/propensity/glPurchaseProbabilities/#{runDate}/#{partition}/glPurchaseProbabilities.tsv/part*” as input to the Pig script.

And my pig script does something like this to load.
s3_consolidated_results = load '$input' using PigStorage('\t', '-noschema')

Can anyone help me with how to intercept that input variable and extract the partition from it and push as a column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A = LOAD 'x' using PigStorage('\t','-tagsource');
```

Quoting from the docs:

`('tagsource') - Add a first column indicates the input file of the record.`

After that you can do a projection to get the part of the filename that you're actually interested in.

Comment: tried that..I keep getting unrecognized option                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -tagsource
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage.<init>(PigStorage.java:187)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -tagsource

Comment: which version of pig are you using?

Comment: I tested it with 0.11.0 and it worked. should be working with 0.10.0 too though (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#pigstorage).

Comment: I checked the code and it didn't have the tagsource option. It has only the 2 schema options.

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/tags/release-0.10.0/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.java?view=markup it is there